# How to run a `scrapy` project as a regular `python` app in order to run it from lambda?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am creating a `scrapy` project and the structure looks like:

[image]

I can run the app via `scrapy` command line `scrapy crawl SPIDER_NAME` but how can I package the app as a regular python program which can be run in AWS `lambda`?
From the command line `scrapy crawl SPIDER_NAME`, I don't know the entry point for the program. Lambda requries `handler` method as its entry point, so how can I trigger the scrapy task programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include `scrapy` in your Lambda package e.g.:

```
pip install scrapy -t YOUR_LAMBDA_ROOT_DIR
```

If you will have multiple Lambdas using `scrapy` it is recommended to install it as a [Lambda Layer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html) to simplify deployment and maintenance. Make sure that `scrapy` and all the dependencies (especially binary) are available from your lambda package.

In order to use `scrapy` as a Lambda one of the approaches is to implement `scrapy.crawler.Crawler` in your lambda_function and call the crawl() method from the lambda_handler.

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html

```
import scrapy

from scrapy.crawler import Crawler
from scrapy.settings import Settings

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    settings = Settings(YOUR_SETTINGS)
    crawler = Crawler(spidercls=YOUR_SPIDER, settings=settings)
    report = crawler.crawl()
```

Please note that you may face Lambda execution time limits and you will probably need to chunk your data to multiple invocations. [sosw package](https://docs.sosw.app/en/latest/) could be useful to simplify that.

Comment: How can I write the `lambda handler` to trigger crawling?

Comment: You probably need to initialize the `scrapy.crawler.Crawler` class of the Scrapy API. During initialization provide your Spiders. Then just use the API method to `crawl` or `stop`.

Some documentation can be found here: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html#crawler-api

Answer (score 0):

`import scrapy` in your **AWS** Python lambda function.